# Slice 2-D array row by row with corresponding rows from identically shaped array

Tags: python, numpy

consider the array `a`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
a = np.random.choice(np.arange(8), (2, 4), False)
print(a)

[[7 1 4 5]
 [6 2 3 0]]
```

I'll create another array `b` that holds the results of `np.argsort` along each row.

```
b = a.argsort(1)
print(b)

[[1 2 3 0]
 [3 1 2 0]]
```

I want to produce the sorted version of `a` by doing an appropriate slice of `a` with `b`.  It should look like this

```
idx0 = np.arange(a.shape[0]).repeat(a.shape[1])
print(a[idx0, b.ravel()].reshape(a.shape))

[[1 4 5 7]
 [0 2 3 6]]
```

***question***
what is the appropriate way to slice an `2 x 4` array with another `2 x 4` array in the fashion described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) for the help -

```
a[np.arange(b.shape[0])[:,None],b]
```

Sample run -

```
In [10]: a
Out[10]: 
array([[7, 1, 4, 5],
       [6, 2, 3, 0]])

In [11]: b
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [3, 1, 2, 0]])

In [12]: a[np.arange(b.shape[0])[:,None],b]
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 4, 5, 7],
       [0, 2, 3, 6]])
```